# Is there a way to change the default artifact store path on Databricks Mlflow?

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I have a cloud storage mounted to Databricks and I would like to store all of the model artifacts there without specifying it when creating a new experiment.

Is there a way to configure the Databricks workspace to save all of the model artifacts to a custom location in DBFS by default?

Answer (score 0):

Best to ask Databricks questions at https://community.databricks.com

Comment: Thanks, I will attempt to get an answer there and then update it here.